# BetterDiscord Plugin: Receiving a variable from the plugin settings, within Discord

Tags: javascript, css, discord, discord.js

I am just getting into discord plugin programming, and I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve a variable input through the plugin settings. I have no example code, sorry, but if anyone knows about discord plugins, please help!

Comment: *(discord.js is for Discord Bots in Node, not BetterDiscord Plugins.)*

Comment: True, thank you for correcting. I thought the rich embed was part of discord.js, but I was mistaken.

Comment: I haven't used the plugin system in a while. It still calls `getSettingsPanel()` function right?

Comment: @Jack that seems to have worked! Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Honestly it's been so long since I wrote my comment that I can't remember what it means! Glad it works though, you can always answer your own question on Stackoverflow for future readers

Comment: Thank you @Jack!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve values from the settings page of Discord, use the `getSettingsPanel()` method.

(Credit to Jack)